# How can I check if two images exist and then do something else

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using Ajax, I check if two image sources are available on the server or not. The Ajax code is the following:

```
        if (result['img_one'] !== '') {
            var src_one = "blah-blah-one.jpg";
            $.ajax({url: src_one,
                success: function(data, textStatus) {
                    $("#profile-box").show();
                    $("#profile-img").attr("src", src_one);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#profile-box').hide();
                }
            });
        }
        if (result['img_two'] !== '') {
            var src_two = "blah-blah-two.jpg";
            $.ajax({url: src_two,
                success: function(data, textStatus) {
                    $("#profile-box").show();
                    $("#profile-pic").attr("src", src_two);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#profile-box').hide();
                }
            });
        }
```

After these two blocks of code, I want to check if both of images are available and loadable or not. However, being a newbie, I cannot do it. Using $.when and .done did not help me, and the problem still preserved. I tried many different ways and various techniques to check if the images exist on the server, however, when checking if both of them are available, I ran into problem. In other words, I can check if each and every image exists, yet when I want to take another action when both of them are available, I get stuck. May you please help.

Even the following functions did not help:

```
function checkImage(url){

    var image = new Image();

    image.src = url;

    if (!image.complete) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (image.height === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and

```
function imageExists (src) {
    var result;
    $("<img>").attr('src', src).on("error", function(e) {
             result =  false;
        })
        .on("load", function(e) {
            result = true;
        });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really possible the way you're using asynchronous functions.

One way is with `Promise`s. Here's a function that loads an image (provided a URL in `src`) and returns a promise to do so:

```
function loadImage( src, imgSelector ) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $(imgSelector).attr('src', src).on("error", function(e) {
      reject( "Unable to load " + src )
    })
    .on("load", function(e) {
      resolve()
    });
  })
}
```

Then you can ask to load two images, and let you know when they're done:

```
Promise.all( [loadImage('first.jpg', '#profile-img'), loadImage('second.jpg', '#profile-pic') ] ).then(
  function(result) {
    console.log("Got 'em all!'")
  }
).catch(function(result) {
  console.log( "Oops, error: " + result )
})
```

When they've both loaded, the "Got 'em all!" message should show in the console. If any fails to load, it will trigger the "Oops, error" message.

Comment: Millions of thanks dear @Kmoser. Your code helped me out of the problem. Yet, may you be kind enough and let me know if you can add some code to you 'function loadImage()' so that the image we are checking if it is available be loaded on a special div.

Comment: @H.M. That should be pretty easy but you'd have to show me in your code which image would go in which `<div>`.

Comment: I have two different divs, and the two images that I check should be loaded in two divs. Can you code them to be dynamic; that is, adding one parameter such as 'div' to your function loadImage( src, div ) then load the picture in that div. Much Much appreciated.

Comment: As you can see in the code above, I have two image sources that the images should be loaded into after making sure they are available: $("#profile-img").attr("src", src_one); and $("#profile-pic").attr("src", src_one);

Comment: Dear @kmoser, I added the comment above. May you please read it at your convenience

Comment: @H.M. I've updated my answer to include the relevant code.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to nest the ajax calls.  Because ajax calls are asynchronous, the browser will not "wait" for the first one to complete before calling the second one.  So the pseudocode would look something like this:

```
ajax(
  {
    url: src1,
    success: function (result) {
       ajax(
         { 
           url: src2,
           success: function (result) {
             // At this point both images are loaded
             box.show();
           }
         }
       )
     }
   }
)
```

A more "modern" approach would be to use Promises or async/await, but this will probably get you what you need using jQuery.

Comment: Nesting does not help me, and it runs me into some other problems. Thanks anyway.